# Stripe checkout autofill or disable customer name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe checkout. I already collect some userdata and I don't want customers to fill in their name twice. How can I autofill or disable the name field?

[image]

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        customer_email: !customerFound ? data.email : undefined,
        customer: customerFound ? customer.id : undefined,
        customer_update: customerFound
          ? {
              address: 'auto',
              name: 'auto',
            }
          : undefined,
        line_items: lineItems,
        client_reference_id: data.userId,
        payment_method_types: ['card', 'bancontact'],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${domain}/betaling-gelukt?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${domain}/betaling-mislukt`,
        locale: 'nl',
        billing_address_collection: 'auto',
        metadata: {
          reservation: data.reservatieId,
        },
      });
```

Comment: this is typescript though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer):

> In payment mode, the customer’s most recent card payment method will be used to prefill the email, name, card details, and billing address on the Checkout page.
>
> In subscription mode, the customer’s default payment method will be used if it’s a card, and otherwise the most recent card will be used. A valid billing address is required for Checkout to prefill the customer’s card details.

This may or may not be ideal for your situation.

---

**Alternatively**, you could completely cut out Stripe Checkout and use [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js) alongside the backend API that Stripe provides. This method has its pros/cons:

**Pros:**

- Total control over the elements and the flows of the elements
- Customise/style elements to your own choosing

**Cons**:

- You have to create the backend and handle `PaymentIntent` and `Subscription` manually

We faced similar issues as yourself and though the initial change from Stripe Checkout to Stripe.js was a bit of learning curve it gave us much more control and allowed us to have payments without needing to redirect to an external site.

**Note:** I've intentionally left out code because the implementation of Stripe.js can vary based on your needs but if needed I can provide some examples.

Comment: thanks man, next project I'll use Stripe.js (=elements?)

Comment: so I'm trying stripe elements now and I have the exact same issue

Comment: @Ruben Stripe elements does not ask for name. I currently use it in several applications to only render the inputs for the card number, expiry, and security code.

Comment: do you use payment_method_types: ['bancontact']? I'm using a payment element maybe it's not the correct one

Comment: @Ruben the only payment method types I use is ‘cards’. Maybe you can share your new code?

Comment: it's the same I'm just using bancontact and that payment method needs a name for some reason. But other shops who offer bancontact never ask for an extra name

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `name` field of the Checkout Session is not necessarily your customer’s name, but the name on the Payment Method they are using.

It’s not possible to prefill this `name` field unless the `customer` already has a Payment Method attached that can be reused with [`​​setup_future_usage`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage).

- For a bancontact Payment Method, this is not possible since it’s for one-time payment only.
- For a card Payment Method, it’s possible. This would prefill the email, name, card details, and billing address as mentioned on the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node#create_checkout_session-customer).

In general I would recommend to let Stripe Checkout collect all the information, and then update your system from that, not the other way around.

Comment: The name is not the name of the payment method, it is the customers name. I need some extra custom fields so I have to collect some information before the checkout, so I might as well collect all the information.